# Adicionar um Grupo do AD a uma lista do Sharepoint 2010 usando o Client Object Model

Tags: sharepoint

Alguem sabe como adicionar um grupo existente no AD a uma lista do Sharepoint 2010?

Até o momento só vi como adicionar um grupo do Sharepoint, mas preciso adicionar um grupo do AD.

```
using (var ctx = new SharepointClient.ClientContext(sharepointSiteUrl))
{
 var groupCreationInfo = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.GroupCreationInformation
 {
    Title = "Nome do Grupo",
    Description = "Descrição do grupo"
 };

 var groupOwner = ctx.Web.SiteGroups.GetByName("GrupoSharepoint"); 
 var group = ctx.Web.SiteGroups.Add(groupCreationInfo);
 group.Owner = groupOwner;
 group.Update();
 ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```